# TrueQ returning False on true, non-numerical statement

Tags: expression-test, logic

I'm trying to test the following logical statement:

```
state = {{1,1,1}};
Or[state != 0, state != Null]
```

but it's returning `False` rather than `True` as I expect it to.

I ran the following `TrueQ` tests, getting the following results:

```
TrueQ[Or[{{1, 1, 1}} != 0, {{1, 1, 1}} != Null]]
TrueQ[{{1, 1, 1}} !=  0]
TrueQ[{{1, 1, 1}} != Null]

False

False

False
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting these results: I don't understand why `TrueQ` is failing to resolve as `True` in these situations. What can I do to make the logical test give me the results I'm looking for -- namely, when `state` is either `0` or `Null`, I get `False`, and get `True` otherwise?

Comment: You probably want `=!=` instead of `!=`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yup, that worked! Thank you! If you add this as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: But why use `TrueQ` at all? `{{1, 1, 1}} =!=  0` evaluates to `True` directly.

Comment: `TrueQ` returns `True` if and only if its argument is identically equal to `True`. Now `{{1, 1, 1}} != Null` remains unevaluated and hence is not `True`, which means `TrueQ` returns `False`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want `=!=` instead of `!=`. See [Unequal](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unequal.html) v [UnsameQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html) for more details.